# The transport failed to connect to the server c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Smtp client and my email functionality not working after upload on server. Everything working fine locally. Below is my code

```
    using System.Web.Mail;        


MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
    mailMsg.From = msgfrom;
    mailMsg.To = "info@magnumhunt.com;";
    mailMsg.Subject = name + " has query for MagnumHunt.com";
    mailMsg.Body = "<table border=1 width=600 cellspecing=5 cellpadding=0><tr><td>Name</td><td>" + name + "</td></tr><tr><td>Email</td><td>" + msgfrom +         "</td></tr><tr><td>Phone</td><td>" + phone + "</td></tr><tr><td>Comment</td><td>" + msgmessage + "</td></tr></table>"; ;
    mailMsg.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;
    mailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
    SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "servername";


    mailMsg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate", "1");
    mailMsg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername", "abc@gmail.com");
    mailMsg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword", "mypassword");
    mailMsg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport", "25");
    mailMsg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl", "true");

    try
    {
       SmtpMail.Send(mailMsg);
}
    catch(Exception ex){}
```

Comment: can you show your webconfig

Comment: <system.net>
    
    
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network defaultCredentials="false" host="myhost" password="mypassword" port="25" userName="abc@gmail.com"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>

Comment: Are you copying your app to a hosted server?  It's possible your ISP is blocking port 25.  You may need to contact them and see if there is an alternate port you can use.

Comment: @Deepika Don't add your code here, edit your original post and add it there. It is more readable that way.

Comment: @DeepikaThakur try to send using `SmtpClient` like `SmtpClient.Send(mailMsg)`